# Python appending class instance to list?

Tags: python

I am attempting to understand how to append instances of classes to lists in Python and I think the way I am doing it is wonky.

For my test code setup I am tracking an object throughout the life of the code. Let's say this object is a man

```
class man_obj():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "name"
        self.height = 0.0
        self.weight = 0.0
        self.action = "action"
```

I create an instance of the object of a man to follow him through his life in my code

```
man_inst = man_obj();
```

I then populate the attributes that make this guy up

```
man_inst.name = "Adam"
man_inst.height = 1.0
man_inst.weight = 1.0
man_inst.action = "looks around"
```

now I want to track him in a list

```
man_list = [];
```

Now what I do next does not feel right but I guess it works.

```
record_man = copy.deepcopy(man_inst);
man_list.append(record_man);
```

And if Adam does something different like decide to get back in shape after a long holiday

```
man_inst.action = "exercise"
man_inst.weight = 0.9
```

now to record what he does I re-use deepcopy and append to list

```
record_man = copy.deepcopy(man_inst);
man_list.append(record_man);
```

I don't think this is the correct way to do this, is there a better way?

here is the code

```
import copy

class man_obj():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "name"
        self.height = 0.0
        self.weight = 0.0;
        self.action = "action";


man_inst = man_obj();


man_inst.name = "Adam"
man_inst.height = 1.0
man_inst.weight = 1.0
man_inst.action = "looks around"

man_list = [];

record_man = copy.deepcopy(man_inst);
man_list.append(record_man);

man_inst.action = "exercise"
man_inst.weight = 0.9               

record_man = copy.deepcopy(man_inst);
man_list.append(record_man);

print("name\theight\tweight\taction")           
for x in range(0, len(man_list)):
    print(man_list[x].name + "\t" + str(man_list[x].height)
    + "\t" + str(man_list[x].weight) + "\t"+ str(man_list[x].action))
```

and here is the results

```
name    height  weight  action
Adam    1.0     1.0     looks around
Adam    1.0     0.9     exercise
```

Comment: The correct way to do *what*? What exactly is your question?

Comment: What makes you think it's not the right way to do it? Aside from the fact that you don't really need a class for this (a dictionary would be fine, although I assume your real code has some behavior that justifies a class), it seems fine to me.

Comment: Using python Dicts ? data = {'adam': instance, 'tom': instance}. override with data['adam'] = new instance.

Comment: Python dicts... there is a joke in there somewhere.